# Tips on how to describe my character using his power

Tags: creative-writing, novel, fantasy, non-fiction

My secondary main character has the power ashes to ashes where he can make his enemy basically start to turn to ash and fade away (think Sandman when he fades away)

I write in 3rd person

Every metahuman (female with power) has two powers while abnormality's (men with power) has only one. Some are dangerous powers while others are not

I don't know how to describe the act of showing the character using his power and describing the power itself

Comment: You should really have edited [the original version of the question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/62524/23927) and flagged it for re-opening, rather than deleting and reposting it. Having closed questions can eventually trigger an automated question ban, but having deleted questions triggers the ban even faster, *and* makes it much more difficult to improve those questions in order to get out of the ban.

Comment: This question is on the borderline of asking for what to write. Have you tried writing these descriptions? What specifically has been the problem with what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main aspects to consider.

### 1. What actions the character takes to use their power/cause it to happen

A good starting point for this part is actually the mechanism of spells form role playing games like dungeons and dragons. In that game spells often have components that are Somatic (movement-based), Verbal (speaking words/making sounds), and material (substances that are needed to cast the spell). Another aspect can be a spell focus (think holy artifact or maybe a wand in other fantasy settings)

So think about which of these aspects would make the best sense for your character, their power, or the story. Maybe your character says arcane words and then mimes flames with their hands. Maybe they just do something more like a small choreographed dance. Maybe they put their hand on their heart and concentrate hard, resulting in the person they are focusing on to turn to ash. Maybe it is something else

### 2. What the power looks like when it "happens"

Try to imagine how you want the target turning to ash. Is there a wind that seems to blow them away or maybe some energy flows from the person with the power to the target or is it like the "dusting" that happened in some marvel movies (where the people just melt/turn to dust with little to no fanfare)

### 3. How the power affects others when it is happening (and any lingering effects)

This is more about the side-effects of the power. Is there a shockwave or maybe some side effects on others like feeling warm or cold? The side effects can also act on the person who used the power. Maybe it drains them of energy and makes them tired or it gives them energy or a rush of power. Or again something else.

Does it leave some kind of lingering effect on witnesses (maybe they feel like part of their soul turned to ash too. maybe they feel like they passed through a fire. Or maybe something else).

### Conclusion

As with most story related points you need to consider what the effect on the story and the characters you want the power to have. This means things like what needs to be done to activate/fire the power, what it looks like and what side-effects it might have.

If you are having trouble figuring out what to choose consider brainstorming options for each aspect and then narrow the list down with pro & con listings for each you like.